# Is it possible to connect SQL Server over internet using computer name with port?

Tags: sql-server, networking, tcp

How can I connect my SQL Server over the internet using my computer name with port. like `MyPCName,1234`.

I Googled and found there are several ways through which I can access using IP address but for that way I'll have to use static IP.

But I don't want to connect using IP address. One of my hosting provider has provided me their server name with port, through which I can connect the SQL Server database easily.

Comment: Why would you want to do this instead of just putting your database in, say, Azure or AWS?

Comment: I don't know, why some people always start demotivating by voting down  if someone don't have any Idea about some topic. This is very unfair for freshers. Next time he/she don't dare to ask any question :(

Comment: For connecting with computer name in stead of IP, that computer will need to be know by the DNS servers. Everytime you surf to a website, your browser has to ask the DNS server what the IP address is for the name you have entered. So, to do this you need to register that computer in the DNS servers, this is not so costly anymore these days

Comment: Well - your question is really kinda off-topic here - this is a site all about **programming** - but this is really more about network technology / DNS resolution / server setup - so I can see that some folks might consider it off-topic and thus downvote (I didn't - just trying to explain potential reasonings)

Comment: @marc_s why there is `networking` and `tcp` tag available if my question is off-topic?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi Those tags exist because some people do _programming_ that involves networking components, drivers and other software that uses tcp, etc. Resolving a network connectivity issue is not a good fit for a site dedicated to solving programming problems.

Answer (score 3):

In the end you will always connect to an IP address. It's just that [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) will resolve an arbitrary domain like e.g. `mydomain.com` to an IP address and connect to that. So what you need is a domain and then create DNS records which point to your machine which is effectively an IP address. When you don't have/ want to use a static IP address [DynDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS#:%7E:text=Dynamic%20DNS%20%28DDNS%29%20is%20a%20method%20of%20automatically,term%20is%20used%20to%20describe%20two%20different%20concepts.) might be an option for you.

There is lots of information available when you google how this works:
I found [this explanation](https://www.verisign.com/en_US/website-presence/online/how-dns-works/index.xhtml) particularly helpful.

### Edit

As mentioned by @Smor in the comments, this is very risky as your exposing your database to the internet i.e. practically anyone in the world could potentially attempt to access your database. Therefore databases are generally not directly exposed to the internet, but rather in a private network which is properly secured (there are many things one could do which are far beyond the scope of this answer) so that only your services e.g. a web app can access it.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi Most importantly, this is a VERY RISKY thing to do! Don't do it without understanding that risk.